# Linkage of a variable defined in a namepace and used in multiple translation units

Tags: c++, namespaces, linkage

1. In C, to use a variable in multiple translation units, we need to
   make sure the variable has external linkage.

   Similarly, in C++, if I want a variable  defined in a namespace to be used in
   multiple translation units, does the variable have to have external
   linkage? How shall I use namespace and linkage together properly?
2. What is the default linkage of a variable defined in a namespace?

Thanks.

Comment: Namespaces have nothing to do, directly, with linkage. In general, C++'s rules in this regard are the same as C's.

Comment: ... except for anonymous namespaces

Answer (score 1):

It works the same as C, except with 'namespace xyz { }' around it, so in your header, you'd have:

`namespace xyz { extern int myglobal; }`

and in the source file where you define it, its storage and initialize it, you would have

`namespace xyz { int myglobal = 0; }`

I'll say as an tangential style comment, that using globals in this way is really not very common in C++; there's usually better ways of creating a shared global state, like static class members (which allows you to create access restrictions by making it protected/private and limiting access through static member functions).